# Como puedo mostrar el radio y el labeljuntos

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo esta funcion que obtiene los datos de un json, y crea labels y radios automaticamente

```
var obj = JSON.parse(respuesta);
                        window.respuesta = obj;

                        function rellenar_checkbox(id, obj) {
                            let elem = document.getElementById(id);

                            while (elem.firstChild) {
                                elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
                            }
                            var check_bundle = document.getElementById('checkBundle');
                            var nombre_factura = document.getElementById('nombre_factura');
                            var numero_factura = document.getElementById('numero_factura')
                            var nits = obj.nits;
                            obj.forEach(dato => {

                                let label = document.createElement("label");
                                let input = document.createElement("input");
                                input.setAttribute("id", dato.nit);

                                input.type = 'radio';
                                input.name = 'nit';

                                label.innerText = dato.nit + dato.razon_social;
                                input.value = dato.nit;

                                label.prepend(input);

                                elem.appendChild(label);

                                var obj1 = JSON.parse(dato.nit);
                                console.log(obj1);

                                input.addEventListener('click', () => {
                                    nombre_factura.value = dato.razon_social;
                                    numero_factura.value = dato.nit;
                                });
                                label.innerText = dato.nit + ' ' + dato.razon_social;
                                check_bundle.append(input);
                                check_bundle.append(label);
                            });
                        }
```

Lo que pasa es que se estan generando los radios y los labels con un salto como la imagen que adjunto, como podria hacer para que se muestren juntos anbos, los radiosy los labels.

[image: Los inputs y labels generados automaticamente se ven asi]

Comment: Algunos elementos tienen por defecto que se muestren el bloque, puedes intentar poniendo al radio y/o al label display: inline;

Answer (score 0):

Una solución aplicable es poner el input dentro del label, pero depende de la configuración CSS del input, puedes validar cómo se está renderizando el input con las herramientas para desarrolladores incluídas en la mayoría de los navegadores (Google Chrome: F12 / Firefox: F12) e inspeccionando uno de los inputs.

En el código mostrado podrías reemplazar la línea:

```
label.prepend(input);
```

con

```
label.appendChild(input);
```